# Can use the commerce kik start with aegir hosting system like a platform!

Tags: commerce, aegir

I'm using Aegir on ubuntu 16.04 using php 7.02.
My question is, can I use this commerce like a platform in the aegir hosting system?
That means that I can't access the installation wizard and I have to go with the installation wizard (or skip it with default values) by drush/ drush-provisione!
It gives me often generic errors about the database table system that it doesn't exist.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Aegir 3 comes with e-commerce for drupal 7, there is not yet a d8 platform, if you are trying the d7 platform and it is not working then you have not installed aegir properly!

The aegir install asks you whether to install platforms ot not, you will have to try the link above or re-install aegir.

For anybody wishing to install aegir properly, make sure you use the instructions here:

http://docs.aegirproject.org/en/3.x/install/

A new linux install is a must!

Comment: thanks for your answer :) but what do you meen with "comes with "?

Comment: https://github.com/omega8cc/boa/blob/master/docs/PLATFORMS.txt

Comment: oh didn't know about it, but how can i install it? witch command can i use?

Comment: So did you get it working? Please post back so other users can benefit

Comment: no, i did not! still have the same problem! i'm using drupal7 but i can not install it again because i have other sites on...aegir works fine with the other sites with other distrubutiones!